# Verifying Facebook accessToken with Koa

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token, koa, verify

I'm working on a SPA which uses Facebook client side authentication. After successful login, for each API request I want to use the `accessToken` on the server side to verify the user. I use Koa.js.

What would be a good way of doing it? I'd be happy to use a middleware for this job if there is any.

Comment: _“for each API request”_ - why, how would that make sense? You do that _once_, after the logged in, so that you can verify which user they are. With every single API call would be nonsense; the token does already “secure” that. Basically all you need to do is send the access token to the server, and there either debug it (see Facebook docs), or make a `/me` request to fetch the details of the user the token belongs to directly.

Comment: Yes, what you're saying sounds about right - it wouldn't make much sense of asking FB on every request the client makes. However, wouldn't this mean I need to maintain a session with client against man-in-the-middle attack? Or is it enough to just use SSL?

Comment: Actually I realised that asking FB on every API request wouldn't prevent man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Well that depends on what specifically you want to achieve here. _“on the server side to verify the user”_ - that means you have your own login system in place already? Then that should be using sessions in some way or form already, no? (Otherwise, how would it be an actual login system.) Using SSL/HTTPS should of course be a given these days, and with that any MITM attack should be rather unlikely already.

Comment: I haven't got login system, I'm just about to start building an API for my SPA. So if I understand you correctly the flow should be as follows: 1) client makes login request to FB, gets the token 2) client makes auth to API with the that token 3) API verifies the token with FB 4) if success API creates a session and sends back the session ID to the client 5) further API queries will contain the session ID - is that right? Is there a middleware that does this job for me? :) Thanks

Comment: No, your API calls will always need the access token. The API does not care about _your_ system’s session, there is absolutely zero connection.

Comment: Then how to avoid asking FB all the time if the user has still got a valid session? Do I need a standalone auth system which maintains a session as well as verifies the token with FB?

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place? You make an API call, when you need an API call. Should the token have expired in the meantime, the resulting error message will tell you ...

Comment: Hmm, ok I think I'm getting it now. On each request the client makes, a token is being sent which will be used for verification. If the API can find a user with that token in the local DB (taking into account the expiration time too) then auth is success. If the API isn't able to verify the user locally then turns to FB, then updates the user in the DB. Is that right? :D

Comment: You said you don't have your own login system, so what exactly do you want to authenticate against here? Why do you want to store any access tokens in the database? Do you have any server-side components that need authentication to access user data or something like that? That again should happen using your own session; you just initially validate the user access token/request their ID, with that they become "logged in" to your session.